# What is a .sln.ide file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution `/Foobar.sln`. It contains one Class Library project and one Unit Test project. A few days ago I noticed a new file `/Foobar.sln.ide/graph/Foobar.sln.ide`.

Contents:

```
<Solution Format="0.0.0.3">
  <Version>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</Version>
</Solution>
```

I'm not sure what I was doing when it was created, since I didn't notice it until a few days after it was created.

Today, several days later than I first asked this question, it appeared again in an Excel VSTO Add-in project. My guess now is that it's related to closing the solution, since it appeared in between the time I committed my changes and the time I opened a new project (not a VS project, just a file being edited). I haven't reproduced it.

What created this file? What does it do? Is it safe to delete? Should it be checked in to source control?

Comment: Did you upgrade to R# 8 lately? I noticed the file too.

Comment: I don't have Resharper installed.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the "Roslyn" compiler.  If so, this creates the .sln.ide folder in your solution folder.  I believe it's to do with complier caching.

Comment: No, I'm not using Roslyn.

Comment: Visual Studio 2014 ships with Roslyn, so a number of curious people may soon be reading this answer.