# What is the purpose of the .sln.ide folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying out Visual Studio 14 CTP 2 and noticed there's this .sln.ide folder:

[image]

There have been a few questions going around about the .sln.ide (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859987/what-is-a-sln-ide-file), [this](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/545124) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/766279d5-f8c5-40b8-8ccc-c2a95f84631d/slnide-file?forum=visualstudiogeneral)), but two of them are about a file (not folder) with that extension in Visual Studio 2012 (not 2014), and the remaining question is unanswered.

From the hints I've seen in those questions, it appears that the folder is created by the [Roslyn compiler](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) for caching purposes. However, I've been unable to find a source that explains exactly what it does.

So what is the purpose of that folder, and how is it used?

Comment: The purpose is to keep programmers that have solutions with dozens of projects and hundreds of source code files happy.

Comment: [If even Jon Skeet doesn't know](https://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/452092455148875776), what hope do the rest of us have? :)

Comment: Not to be confused with any `.sln.ide` *file* which is probably made by another app http://stackoverflow.com/q/17859987/284795

Comment: In all case, it should be excluded from the source control (add *.sln.ide/ to .gitignore): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/03/announcing-web-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx

Comment: You can add *.sln.ide/ in .gitignore file

Answer (score 10):

It

> ...is used by Roslyn Compiler engine to store temporary files.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/03/announcing-web-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As my inspect, Visual Studio 2015 RTM never use this folder again, you can delete it. If you had used `.tfignore`/`.gitignore` to ignore `.sln.ide`, you can delete it too. Cause it won't be generated anymore.

It now uses hidden `.vs` folder, with the same files in `.vs\(solution name)\v14\vbcs.cache`. Some of them have `.vs\(solution name)\vbcs.cache`, I believe it has been used in some preview versions of VS 2015, already been replaced by `v14\vbcs.cache` and can be deleted too. And also you can delete `(solution name).v14.suo` because it's been replaced by `.vs\(solution name)\v14\.suo`.